Correct approach for creating a modular application in C#
I am currently trying to develop an application (Windows Form), where the main objective is to establish a serial monitor, and an interface for board-specific controls (I have several similar modular boards, where the baseboard is the same, but add-ons change, like digital inputs, outputs, analog, etc.). Most of the communication occurs behind the curtains, so the user is provided by a clear view of the state of different addresses of the board.
My initial approach was to create the serial interface in the [Design] of the form, and create separate classes for each module, where I do them by code, and add them to a panel in the main form. However, to make the visual changes this way takes time and a lot of code, and my generated interface looks bad. The advantage is that I can derive classes and reuse code.
Now I am thinking if the better approach isn't to just create everything in the design interface, and then just have the communication code in the back, but I wouldn't be able to derive all Add-Ons from a template base class, as I am creating something like this everytime:
namespace boardTestTerminal
{
    public partial class boardAddOn1 : UserControl
    {
        public boardAddOn1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

where I derive from UserControl, not from a base AddOn class, so all methods have to be repeated for every AddOn.
I am inexperienced in objective design principles and would like to do this correctly. Any guidance on how to create optimally such applications is greatly appreciated. Also looking for general remarks regarding application creation, splitting into classes, making things reusable and modular (where to find the practical knowledge, too).
Best regards,
AW
Diagram of the application

there should not be any problem to create a base class for a user control. But there is a trend towards "composition over inheritance". So if you have a bunch of common functionality for add-ons you probably want to put that in a common, non-inherited class.

Also note that c# uses generics, not templates. And while it is possible to create generic usercontrols it is somewhat tricky in winforms. WPF & MVVM  is somewhat better in this regard.

Thank you, I read some more about the things you mentioned. I also found a mistake which made me think some things are not possible, I copied from my form.cs the InitializeComponent method for my UserControl classes, and had errors for not existing functions. Now I know it is generated if I add something in the design view.
